# Tags Implementation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, core-data, tags, entity-relationship

I have a "Note" entity for my application, where its attributes are "Title", "Body", and "Tags".

I'm having trouble with the "Tags" attribute; I want to be able to input multiple tags when creating the Note, and then the program will be able to give me other Notes that have the same tag (Exactly like how Stackoverflow uses tags for questions). I'm not quite sure what the relationship between the entities should be.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Tag entity and add to-many relationship from Note to Tag and also to-many relationship from Tag to Note (and set set them to be inverses of each other).

Answer (score 2):

`Tag` shouldn't be an attribute, but a many-to-many relationship. A `Note` can have multiple `Tags` (I assume) and a `Tag` can be added to multiple different `Notes`.

This way you'll be able to set up a fetch request to return all the `Notes` that have a specific `Tag`.